# Select country state and city from combobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

**For desktop application in Java Swings,..**
Suppose there are 3 combo box.
SELECT COUNTRY
SELECT STATE 
SELECT CITY
if i select any country from country conutrylistbox 
values in the state will get automatically inserted with
database values>>
THEN on selection of state ,city will be inserted in city
combo box

If you can help then please Help me...

Comment: You should use Ajax to fill dropdown.

Comment: What have you try, and what is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing elements of a JComboBox according to the selection from another JComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336711/changing-elements-of-a-jcombobox-according-to-the-selection-from-another-jcombob)

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Try creating 3 ComboBox.

**2.** Fill the First ComboBox statically, with all the countries name.

**3.** Each Country will have mapping to its states.

eg:

```
    HashMap<"String",ArrayList<States>>();
```

**4.** Once the Country is selected all the States are fetched from database, and inserted in the ArrayList<> mapped to that country.

**5.** Similary each state will be associated with its cities using HashMap.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to rephrase your question. As per my understanding,

I'd suggest you to use an [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) , [itemStateChanged()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html#itemStateChanged%28java.awt.event.ItemEvent%29).

Also, have a look at [Handling Events on a Combo Box.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners)